# how to get rails angular app to render jade templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pug

I'm trying to render jade templates from app/assets/javascripts/templates and I can't seem to get things to work.  am getting chrome console errors,

```
GET http://localhost:3000/templates/lunch.jst.jade 404 (Not Found)
```

what direction should I be going with this ? Thanks !

source repository on github

https://github.com/jcdavison/lookingtolunch/

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
//= require_tree ./app
//= require_tree ./templates
```

app.js.coffee

```
Lunch = angular.module('lunch', ['ngRoute'])
Lunch.config([ '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  # $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "../templates/test.jst", controller: "LunchCtrl" } )
  $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "../templates/lunch.jst.jade", controller: "LunchCtrl" } )
  # $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "test.jst", controller: "LunchCtrl" } )
  # $routeProvider.otherwise( { templateUrl: "test.html", controller: "LunchCtrl" })
])
```

app/assets/javascripts/templates/lunch.jst.jade

```
h1 some text goes here
```

config/initializers/jader.rb -used for jade preprocessing following configuration instructions from https://github.com/zohararad/jader

```
Jader.configure do |config|
  config.views_path = Rails.root.join('app','assets','javascripts','templates')
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.0"

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem "haml", "~> 4.0.4"
gem "angularjs-rails", "~> 1.2.7"
gem "zeus", "~> 0.13.3"
gem "pg", "~> 0.17.1"
gem "pry-debugger", "~> 0.2.2"
gem "devise"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-twitter"
gem "uuidtools"
gem "quiet_assets", "~> 1.0.2"
gem "thin", "~> 1.6.1"
gem "jader", "~> 0.0.8"
gem "ngmin-rails", "~> 0.4.0"

group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.1"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end


group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

and of course, some screenshots...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using require.js? There is a plugin to render and load the templates 100% client side - https://github.com/deedubs/require-jade